# Hibernate criteria returning list which contain same objects

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

We recently upgraded the hibernate version from 3.1 to 4.3.1 for our application. I am facing a weird issue, wrong and same object is always getting associated with the result object.

I have a class ClinicalStudyEvent which contains collection of EventFormContext Class. When I tries to fetch ClinicalStudyEvent on the basis of eventId using HQL, hibernate is associating same object of EventFormContext with result object. Same collection object for every eventid.

**Classes**

ClinicalStudyEvent

```
public class ClinicalStudyEvent implements
        Comparable<ClinicalStudyEvent>
{
.....
private Set<EventFormContext> eventFormContexts = new   LinkedHashSet<EventFormContext>();
......
 }
```

EventFormContext:

```
public class EventFormContext extends CSFormContext
{
....
private ClinicalStudyEvent clinicalStudyEvent;
....
}
```

**Hibernate Mappings:**

ClinicalStudyEvent

```
     <set
        name="eventFormContexts"
        table="EVENT_FORM_CONTEXT"
        lazy="false"
        inverse="true"
        cascade="all"
        order-by="IDENTIFIER">
          <key column="CLINICAL_STUDY_EVENT_ID"/>
      <one-to-many class="edu.wustl.clinportal.domain.EventFormContext"/>
    </set>
```

CSFormContext

```
 <hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
   <class
    name="edu.wustl.clinportal.domain.CSFormContext"
    table="CS_FORM_CONTEXT"
    dynamic-update="false"
    dynamic-insert="false">
............
<joined-subclass
        name="edu.wustl.clinportal.domain.EventFormContext"
        table="EVENT_FORM_CONTEXT" >
        <key column="IDENTIFIER" />
......
<many-to-one 
    name="clinicalStudyEvent"
    class="edu.wustl.clinportal.domain.ClinicalStudyEvent" cascade="none"
    update="true" insert="true" column="CLINICAL_STUDY_EVENT_ID"  />

    </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

For every ClinicalStudyEvent class we are getting the same object of EventFormContext  class.

I also checked the sql by changing the show_sql parameter which is also correct.
I checked the database and the tables for all three classes has primary keys.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Can you post the HQL you are using to fetch data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes and hbm used in this query is given at https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043003&start=0&hilit=ClinicalStudyEvent

Looks like a bug in hibernate4.3 as it was not adding a condition to join sub classes. I resolved it by changing lazy to true and explicitly fetching objects when required.